# Uk based Sms api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net, sms

We want to integrate our system with SMS api.I have researched and found there are so many SMS APIs & SMS API providers. Can anyone recommend me  most popular,easy to use and cheap UK based SMS gateways for sending and receiving SMS ?